# "Message box info is absent" error using get-last-message-box

Tags: eclipse-rcptt

I am trying to verify a text in a text field in a native dialog using the rcptt framework. The code I am using is:

```
set-dialog-result Folder

get-window "Open Project" | get-group "Project Details"
 | get-button "..." | click

get-last-message-box | get-property Folder 
| equals "apiprojects" | verify-true
```

However, I receive Message box info is absent error on the get-last-message-box function. I couldn't find any info on this error in the net. Could you , please help?

Answer (score 0):

Command `get-last-message-box` returns a MessageBoxInfo object, which has two relevant properties only: title and message. It can not be extended with a "Folder" property.

[Source Code](https://github.com/xored/rcptt/blob/a37c7c109ee5659b909797b32ed8e252d9f9a387/core/org.eclipse.rcptt.tesla.ecl/gen-src/org/eclipse/rcptt/tesla/ecl/model/MessageBoxInfo.java)

Comment: Thanks for that! Is it at all possible then to get the info that I need for this  native window?  It is a window "Browse For Folder" and I want to get the path to the folder it is pointing to. When I am recording and I change the path, this is what is recorded: set-dialog-result Folder "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\apiprojects"

Comment: And why do you want to verify that? I mean, unless you are testing RCPTT itself, verifying something you've just set is quite useless, right?

Comment: No, I am not verifying what I set. I am trying to verify what is set when I open the window. The code I sent in the last comment is just to show what I am getting when I record something related to that window.

Comment: You mean like what is set by default? Or in other words, what is the default proposed location?

Comment: Yes, exactly. We had a bug with the location and now I need to verify it is pointing to the correct  folder.

Comment: So that's it, no answer?